# "Increase in Entropy Principle"

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

[image]I have a question about the "Increase in Entropy Principle". As you can see from the figure, For adiabtic processes $\Delta S>0$. This is because of the Eq. (3). If I consider the adiabatic process hypothesis from the Eq. (1), this leads to the nonsense $0>0$. Should I deduce from that the reversible process is not considered adiabatic? I have three book of Thermodynamics at my house, but no one focuses on this detail, except one (not in english) that specify the adiabatic condition just for the irreversible system. I already did reasearches in internet, but I did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you determine the change in entropy for an irreversible process, you need to devise an alternate reversible path between the same two end states, and determine the change in entropy for this alternate reversible path.  For an irreversible adiabatic process, there exists no adiabatic reversible path between the same two end states.  Any reversible path between the same two ends states is going to involve heat transfer, and will not be adiabatic.  All reversible paths (and there are an infinite number of them) between these same two end states will yield the same value (> 0) for the integral of dQ/T.  This is the entropy change for the adiabatic irreversible path.

Comment: In any process on a closed system, there are only two ways that the entropy of the system can change:  1) entropy generation as a result of irreversibility within the system and 2) entropy transfer by heat flow across the boundary of the system.  In the case of an adiabatic irreversible process, only the first mechanism is present, so the entropy change of the system must be positive.  In an adiabatic reversible process, neither mechanism is present, so the entropy change of the system is zero.  So there is no adiabatic reversible process with a positive entropy change.